# Div doesnt go on bottom of screen

Tags: css, html, alignment

My footer seems to interrupt my div bar, and doesnt show until i scroll to the footer, 
It is supposed to show up at the bottom of the screen not the bottom of the page, and on the bottom of the footer, Help!

I have tried changing the margin, but that wouldnt make it responsive

Site: http://ultimaterealms.us/MediaUniverse.php

How i want it to be: http://goo.gl/wsJEcj

Comment: Why not just make the div have `fixed` positioning, tied to the bottom of the screen? `position:fixed;bottom:0px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the `position: relative;` on the `#wrapper`, and on the `body`, then your `#info` will not position itself relative to it, rather relative to the screen.

You will also have to update `#info` to have a z-index of 2 or higher to sit above the `#main`.

Comment: The fiddle you sent me is on the bottom of the page, i want it on the bottom of the screen

Comment: Sorry, now I'm confused as to what it is you want :) The fiddle you provided is how you want it, but not how it is. Do you have a fiddle of how your code actually is so we can look at that?

Comment: It would be alot to paste on here, but the html of my site ( linkProvided in the question) can be looked at with Developer tools on the browser

Comment: Also note that https://mega.co.nz/# has the bar that i am trying to accomplish, See how it is on the bottom of your screen no matter what resolution? And when you scroll a huge chunk of stuff shows up, as in my case i want it to be the footer

Comment: Okay so you want the footer to be on the bottom of the screen, and fixed to the bottom of the screen (always stays there) as you scroll?

Comment: Not exactly, that would be a "sticky footer", But i just want a bar on the bottom of anyones screen that tells people to scroll down for my footer, which is on my site when you scroll all the way down

Comment: And the fiddle i included is how i wanted it, But as you might have noticed, its not working on my site due to the special footer i have, This is what im trying to fix, The footer is making the bar go on the bottom of the footer instead of the screen

Comment: Well, go to ultimaterealms.us/MediaUniverse.php and see it made the footer moveable, This is incorrect, Also, i thank you for trying to fix this problem, But have i still got you confused of what im trying to achieve?

Comment: Think I've got it now :) How's that, is it what you want?

Comment: setek, i did what you said it looks much better, But it didnt do what i wanted it to do, Since you have improved it i thank you, I ask of one more thing, Go on my site, I just want it so i cant scroll at all

Comment: I'm not sure if that'll be considered a separate topic/issue, but ... why do you have `600px` of bottom padding on `#main`? Is it just to make space for the footer? If so, you can reduce the size of it so that your page isn't so tall anymore.

Comment: Thank you! Im sorry for taking alot of your time, But you really helped me alot!

Comment: Glad to have helped :) If this answer is right, can you mark it as right? thanks :)

Comment: Yes, if i knew how xD